# Transactions in Mongodb node js failed with error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to add transactions in mongodb but it fails with the following error

"This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string"

I changed my connection string also to mongodb://localhost/?retryWrites=false then also the error comes.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Monogodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/)

> Retryable writes require a replica set or sharded cluster, and do not support standalone instances.

With your question it looks like you are using standalone instance over `localhost`.
Create a [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication) and you should be good.

Comment: You need to create the replica set, otherwise it won't work. Edited my answer.